# Ruby on Rails - Errno::EACCES (Windows 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I installed Ruby (v. 2.0.0) and Rails (v. 4.0.4). When i try to start server (using the command `rails s`) i get an error:

```
Could not find gem 'rails (<= 4.0.3) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

After using `bundle install` i get permission error:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - D:/Ruby200/bin/rake.bat
An error occurred while installing rake (10.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I also tried to install older version of rails but it gives Errno::EACCES error too. Rake installation is not possible for the same reason

I use Windows 7 Professional. Command Prompt is run as admnistrator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on windows. use rails installer to install rails on windows.

Find it here.

```
http://railsinstaller.org/en
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I get the same error in this version.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a solution, but Rails development on Windows has just gotten worse in recent years. You are constantly going to run into problems like this.

I think the best solution is:

Download [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)

Download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Then use something like [rails-dev-box](https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box).

Then you can do all your work on your host machine, Windows, while running Rails and your gems in a VM.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a port problem

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --host YOUR-HOST --port YOUR-PORT
```

Replace HOST: 127.0.0. and PORT: from 2000 - 5000

For example: `bundle exec jekyll serve --host 127.0.0.2 --port 20000`

It worked for me.